# Grafana: using instance label in title field of stats panel

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

i’m searching for a possibility to show the instance label `(node_boot_time_seconds{instance="***.local:9100"})` in the title field of a stats panel. There is a hover message

```
Template Variables:
${__series.name}
${__field.name}
$__cell_{N} / $__calc
```

[on the title box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cleqh.png)

Maybe you have an idea!

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `Legend` field in your query section like this :

[image]

The title of panel will be replaced with this name or pattern

Answer (score 0):

You might get node labels and save them in dashboard variable, then you might use it in chart title as well